# Why aren't commits to this Git repository showing up in a branch on Launchpad?

Tags: launchpad, bazaar

[This branch here](https://code.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/libwebp/trunk) is supposed to be importing code from the following Git repository:

```
http://git.chromium.org/webm/libwebp.git
```

However, it isn't. According to "Recent revisions" further down the page, the latest commit was May 14 of this year. This **does not** correspond with [the actual revision history of the Git repository](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=webm/libwebp.git) (the latest commit was 11 days ago).

[Here is the output from the latest import](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/111909110/george-edison55-libwebp-trunk.log) (20 minutes ago).

What is going on? There aren't any errors - just nothing getting imported.

Comment: I'd try asking this on Launchpad itself. LP devs actually read the questions, and they can dig into the problem deeper.

Comment: The Launchpad branch page, before the list of logs: Last successful import was on 2012-05-15. So Launchpad recognizes that the git branch is not being imported. When, on my 12.04 system, I tried ` bzr git-import  http://git.chromium.org/webm/libwebp.git` it worked with the latest revision on 7/23/2012.

Comment: I think andrewsomething has a good idea. Looks to me like a problem the launchpad administrators would have to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the Git importer on Launchpad (which is basically bzr-git, http://launchpad.net/bzr-git). I've seen this issue before when fetching branches over HTTP.

It might be worth filing a bug in launchpad about this (https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+filebug) if there isn't one already.

Answer (score 0):

The Launchpad wiki page https://help.launchpad.net/VcsImports gives some advice on dealing with importing issues. Combining that with Jelmer's answer I would recommend to try in the following order:

1. ask around on #launchpad on Freenode
2. file a bug on https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+filebug
3. mail the Launchpad team at feedback@launchpad.net

Based on your branch's page in Launchpad and a `git clone` of the Git repository it's quite clear that there is a problem.

I'm curious what will happen if you perform the import locally on your PC and push your local branch to Launchpad. Will that bring Launchpad back to a sane state so that it can continue importing new revisions that will be added later in the Git repository? Or what if you delete and import again?